# Aggregate using 2 arrays and keep contribution information

Tags: clickhouse

**Issue**

Want to aggregate rows, but still keep information of how rows tributes to the final sum.

The information is in two arrays, but can't figure out how to aggregate it and keep information.

**Schema & sample data** (simplified)

```
CREATE TABLE A 
(
    Groupkey Int32,
    Sizename String,
    Givenqty Array(int),
    Category Array(int)
) Engine = Memory ;
                
INSERT INTO A VALUES (1, 'XS', [1], [154]);               
INSERT INTO A VALUES (1, 'M', [1], [154]);               
INSERT INTO A VALUES (1, 'L', [1], [154]);                
INSERT INTO A VALUES (1, 'XL', [1,1,2,1,1], [145,145,146,154,145]);

SELECT * FROM A:
```

[image: Sample data]

**Desired result**

I would like 1 aggregated row with the sum of "givenqty pr category".

The result should be: (145 = 3, 146 = 2, 154= 4):

[image: Result]

When doing the query I know the possible outcomes of the "Category" column, so we can use this information to add the value by index (sorted by categorynumber).

The number of categories can be random in the data, but the full range is known when querying the data (can be used as a helping array if solution requires it).

I've tried different kinds of groupArray, tuples etc, but can't seem to get I solved :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the aggregate function [sumMap](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/aggregate-functions/reference/summap/) this way:

```sql
SELECT
    groupKey,
    sumMap(category, givenqty) AS summap,
    summap.2 AS result
FROM 
( 
    /* Emulate the test dataset. */
    SELECT
        data.1 AS groupKey,
        data.2 AS givenqty,
        data.3 AS category
    FROM 
    (        
        SELECT arrayJoin([(1, [1], [154]), (1, [1], [154]), (1, [1], [154]), (1, [1, 1, 2, 1, 1], [145, 145, 146, 154, 145])]) AS data
    )
)
GROUP BY groupKey

/*
┌─groupKey─┬─summap──────────────────┬─result──┐
│        1 │ ([145,146,154],[3,2,4]) │ [3,2,4] │
└──────────┴─────────────────────────┴─────────┘
*/
```